# Custom tooltip on Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I wanted to use a similar tooltip as is displayed when we over the videos on this ASP.NET Ajax site. 
http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos

Which control is this? Is it the animation control?
How to use a similar tootlip on my controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly the  [Popup Control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx) from the Ajax Control Toolikit, but not necessarily.  This is very simple to do with css and javascript using a hidden div element and a mouseover event.

There's some sample code you can use here: http://www.willmaster.com/blog/css/floating-layer-at-cursor-position.php

Comment: I tried using that popup control on a button. The popup comes up when the button is clicked. However, I wanted to changed its behavior so that it appears when mouse enters the button and hides when the mouse goes out of the button. How can that be done?

Comment: Use the javascript/css example in my second link.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of Jquery plug-ins that will do similar things.
Here's an example of one - http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin