# How to show more information behind the text in html asp.net application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have `asp.net` application and I want to get a small pop up window when I hover my mouse over certain text or heading etc. I have put title of that text or heading but thats is not my requirement. I have to keep mouse for atleast 2 to 3 seconds and then it shows a small pop up with information.

```
<td style="background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; border:1px solid #FFFFFF"><b title = "HV-Batterie entspricht der Traktionsbatterie des Fahrzeugs
(Energiequelle)
">HV-Batterie <font color="red">[?]</font></b></td>
```

webpage shows like this

[image]

I have another example below. I want that when I move mouse over the link it should display a pop up window very quickly

[image]

Comment: You can easily get this done by jquery. This can help you http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Maybe you can find useful this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703773/custom-tooltip-on-controls 

Bye!

Comment: @AlfonsoGagliardi problem solved by your suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a tooltip. You can find tons of examples online and decide which one you like best.

If you do a google search for `jquery tooltip`, or `css tooltip`, you should be able to quickly find what you're looking for.

Here is a nice plugin: https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos